# Symmetric gauge in Landau level

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, hilbert-space

Is it possible to solve Hamiltonian of symmetric gauge case of Landau level and explain infinite degeneracy without using ladder operator?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/145510/landau-level-degeneracy-in-symmetry-gauge-finite-system
Is your question the same as this one?

Comment: Yeah but there it was solved in a differnt way.i want to solve it by canonical transformation. But this i am not getting infinite degeneracy.